# Solve the integral $ \int{\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-5x+6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+5x+6}}}dx $

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

My attempt:
\begin{align} \int{\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2-5x+6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+5x+6}}}dx &\\ &=\int{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+5x+6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+5x+6}}}dx+\int{\frac{-\sqrt{x^2+5x+6}-\sqrt{x^2+5x+6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2-5x+6}}}dx \\
&=x-\int{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+5x+6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+5x+6}}}dx-\int{\frac{\sqrt{x^2-5x+6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+5x+6}}}dx \\
&=x-I_1-I_2
\end{align}
I know how to solve the integral $I_1$ using [Euler substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution), but I don't know how to solve the integral $I_2$.

Comment: It is not something to take as a completely strong base, but Wolfram gives a horrible, nightmarish solution to this thing. Are you sure the integrand function is correct?

Comment: @DonAntonio this is how it is written in the book, maybe they made a mistake.

Comment: @Gj Indeed...or maybe there's some slick trick to solve this and give a more or less "normal" answer which WA cannot see... Anyway, it looks pretty terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\int\dfrac{x-\sqrt{x^2-5x+6}}{x+\sqrt{x^2+5x+6}}~dx$

$=\int\dfrac{x-\sqrt{(x-3)(x-2)}}{\sqrt{(x+3)(x+2)}+x}~dx$

$=\int\dfrac{\left(x-\sqrt{(x-3)(x-2)}\right)\left(\sqrt{(x+3)(x+2)}-x\right)}{\left(\sqrt{(x+3)(x+2)}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{(x+3)(x+2)}-x\right)}~dx$

$=\int\dfrac{x\sqrt{(x+3)(x+2)}}{5x+6}~dx+\int\dfrac{x\sqrt{(x-3)(x-2)}}{5x+6}~dx-\int\dfrac{x^2}{5x+6}~dx-\int\dfrac{\sqrt{(x+3)(x+2)}\sqrt{(x-3)(x-2)}}{5x+6}~dx$